# create an automatic bold for table by the ID ?? with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

first of all I apologize for my bad English, I want to make a JavaScript for a tabele who makes himself automatically by the ID Bold, just like this one here but the code is not only for weeks for tabele
the table has therefore different time input I will when the time is for example 08:00 clock, the tabele from 08:15 to mark Irish always +1

```
<td id="1">08:00</td>
<td id="1">BEKA-KAQANIK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="2">08:15</td>
<td id="2">MEDINA</td>
```

Here is an example but it is only on weekdays

http://jsfiddle.net/c5bHx/

```js
var days = 'sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday'.split(',');

document.getElementById( days[(new Date()).getDay()] ).className = 'bold';
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="monday">Monday: 12:00-2:00</div>
<div id="tuesday">Tuesday: 11:00-3:00</div>
<div id="wednesday">wednesday: 12:00-2:00</div>
<div id="thursday">thursday: 11:00-3:00</div>
<div id="friday">friday: 12:00-2:00</div>
<div id="saturday">saturday: 11:00-3:00</div>
<div id="sunday">sunday: 12:00-2:00</div>
```

Comment: Something like this maybe -> http://jsfiddle.net/exs9bh26/

Comment: which is the same as the example that I posted here, something approved via the time of tabele and and nechste marked teoretisch +1

Comment: Uhm, it does account for the time, but if you think it's the same as you've posted, I might be going blind ?

Comment: I apologize to you, by my poor English I do not have as good geschirieben The problem with me is the time zumbeispiel 8.00 clock, must be gelefsen and then the nechste id of 8.15 marks automatically

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is an example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sinanbolel/z24p4mwf/1/). It might help with what you're trying to accomplish.

```html
<table>
    <tr id="1530">
        <td>15:30</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1545">
        <td>15:45</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1600">
        <td>16:00</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
// Initialize new Date object.
var currentDate = new Date();

// Get the hour
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();

// Get the minutes 
var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();

// Bin the minutes to 15 minute increments by using modulus
// For example, xx:33 becomes 30
var minuteBin = currentMinute - (currentMinute % 15);

// Create a string that matches the HTML ids
var idString = "" + currentHour + minuteBin;

// Set the matching div class to 'bold' 
document.getElementById(idString).className = 'bold';

// Log variables to console for debugging
console.log("Time =",currentHour,":",currentMinute,"bin =",minuteBin,"idString =",idString);
```

This example is meant for GMT-0400 (EDT). This will give different results in different time zones.

If I've misunderstood anything, please let me know and I will do my best to update my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: I try to bring that to run but I can not get my maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: EU timezone Austria now is 21:55 06/07/2015
UTC +01: 00 Amsterdam, Berlin Wiena

Comment: Try it now http://jsfiddle.net/sinanbolel/z24p4mwf/2/ - if none of the choices are bold, let me know what the console says.

Comment: it is not bold, it see all the same
no single marker :( :( :( I do not know why

Comment: Can you check the JavaScript console and let me know what you see?

Comment: I see the hir I posted in response

Comment: That's the JavaScript code, but what is the output of `console.log()`? What browser are you using? If you're using Google Chrome, [this is how you use the Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

Comment: Okay, so go to the console by using the keyboard shortcut Command + Option + J (Mac) or Control + Shift + J (Windows/Linux).

Comment: now has worked for me the time is 22:15 and it was bold, I say thank you 10000 time

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. If there is anything else you need clarified to accept the answer, let me know. Remember, when the time reaches 22:30, it will stop working again. This is because the table only has `<tr>` elements with ids `2145`, `2200`, `2215`. If you want to make it work for other times, you'll have to add `<td>`s with those corresponding ids. Also remember that this will work differently for every timezone. For example, you see 22:15 as bold, but I don't see any bold since I'm in EDT. You can use UTC time to standardize it if you need to.

Comment: If there is no div matching the current time, you will see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null` in the console, since a div with the corresponding id will not be found.

Comment: Ok I understand how I can work with it, and hammer out what I need 1000 thanks as I accept the answer I'm pretty new at this websites?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again that what I was doing when the time is different that's very important, for example, 08:44, 08: 49,08: 51,09: 00

Comment: You're not bothering me. I'm sorry, I do not understand what you're asking. Are you saying that the times should be for specific intervals instead of by 15 minute increments?

Comment: Yes, the time is different :(

Comment: Sinan Bolel can you help me pleas ? about this ?